# Hello World app issues

Tags: ios, swift

I made a simple hello world app. I want the button to change to different text names every time I tap the button. I want the label to say "hello", and if I tap the button again, I want it to say "goodbye". I want this change every single time I tap the button. I have tried for days and I still dont get it.

here is the code: 
    import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var labelText: UILabel!
    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if labelText.text == "hello" {
        } else {
            labelText.text = "goodbye"
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

like this?

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    if labelText.text == "hello" { //or labelText.text.equals("hello") for string comparison
        labelText.text = "goodbye"
    } 
    else {
        labelText.text = "hello"
    }
}
```